# How to allow for null parameters in API Attribute Routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have a method which conducts a search based on 3 criteria:

- Author
- Title
- Keywords

The API method I have created for this search currently looks like this:

```
[Route("A={author};T={title};K={keywords}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string author, string title, string keywords)
{            
    //Code for search
}
```

The method works perfectly fine when all 3 parameters are passed. However, if I were to simply just enter an author and **not** title or keywords, I receive a `Not Found` error.

Is there a way I can modify the route to allow for when 1 or more parameters are null/empty strings?

Answer (score 0):

Any parameters not mentioned in the `Route` string will be mapped when sent as part of the query string of the URL. For example:

`http://www.yourapi.com/path/to/endpoint?author=DouglasAdams&keywords=Hitchhiker`

will call your method with `author = "DouglasAdams"`, `title = null`, and `keywords = "Hitchhiker"` if you use `Route("path/to/endpoint")`.